# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker propagation keypress event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Some application have to have 'next gui-control on Enter press' functionality. We use code below to register global handler, but it doesn't work on Bootstrap 3 Datepicker. Does anybody suggest some way that we can 'override' default behavior?

Here is core for registering global handler for keypress event:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  focusable: function (el, index, selector) {
    return $(el).is('a, button, :input, [tabindex]');
  }
});
$(document).on('keypress', 'input,select,textarea', function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get all focusable elements on the page
    var $canfocus = $(':focusable');
    var index = $canfocus.index(document.activeElement) + 1;
    if ($canfocus.eq(index).attr('tabindex') == -1) index++;
    if (index >= $canfocus.length) index = 0;
    $canfocus.eq(index).focus();
  }
});
```

We use this DP: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

jQuery JavaScript Library is v2.1.4

Bootstrap v3.3.5

Code on the page for Datapicker is:

```
<form ...>
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Date">Datum</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">

        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
          <input type="text" id="Date" name="Date" >
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format: 'L' });
          });
        </script>

        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

With this code, nothing happened on 'Enter' where the datapicker is in focus.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/RR4hw/1220/

Comment: Is there mandatory to have HTML structure like you write? Is there possible that problem can be in HTML structure? We have different structure of HTML around the datapicker? I will update question HTML with more HTML.

Comment: I cant imagine the html structure affecting the keypress

Comment: Code for for registering global handler for keypress event is in separate file, and we load it script link in header tag. In Browser debug, we can't catch event for the DataPicker. Code above work fine in jsfiddle.net.

Comment: We have just downloaded full page from http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and add java-script code at the end of file, and we can't detect key-press event. I thing that you example in  jsfiddle.net is with different version of some java-script lib.

Comment: create a working fiddle of the libraries you are using.

Comment: Here is link http://jsfiddle.net/gekvf59r/ with lib we use. As you can see, moving focus stuck on DataPicker.

Comment: heres a way [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gekvf59r/1/), overload the keydown and trigger a custom event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `keydown` event handler within the `datetimepicker` which stops propagation, therefore stopping the `keypress` event.

One option is to overload the `keydown` event and call a custom event, passing the `which` along, then call the original event for the `keydown`:-

```
// get original keydown event
var h = jQuery._data($('#datetimepicker1 input')[0], "events").keydown[0].handler;
// override keydown
jQuery._data($('#datetimepicker1 input')[0], "events").keydown[0].handler = function(e) {
  // create a new custom event and trigger it with 'which' passed
  var event = $.Event('dpkeydown');
  event.which = e.which;
  $(this).trigger(event);
  // call original keydown event 
  h(e);
}

// now watch for 'dpkeydown'
$(document).on('keypress dpkeydown', 'input,select,textarea', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
     .....
```

Comment: Just fyi, place the above code inside  jQuery(function () { }); in order to use jQuery._data().